# uwsgi / mod_wsgi handling pylons redirect_to & error pages

Tags: pylons, django-urls, mod-wsgi, http-status-code-302, uwsgi

My stack is nginx > uwsgi > pylons.

If I use redirect_to on a controller, the app throws a 302 error.  Also I don't see any 404 or 500 error pages anymore that worked fine in paste.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME    '';
```

Add that to your nginx config.